# Insert selected item into text area jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im creating a form where you can add/create standard and custom comments. I've got it already working bout inserting it blablabla. Now im trying to add a select box with 6-7 standard comments. I got that working and I can also log that in to the console which is selected.

Now I'm trying to insert that selected comment into my redactor. The internet can't help me so far yet and I have no clue what to do left. Can you guys help me a little bit or give me tips on how to do it.

Comment Choice is my selector. Editor is my redactor. Here is what I've tried:

```
$('.commentChoice').change(function(){
    //Logging to see what i selected with my .commentChoice
    console.log($(this).val());
    //Trying to add the value of the .commentChoice to the .editor class.
    $('.editor').val($(this).val());
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that `.commentChoice` is a `select` and `.editor` is the `textarea` then there is no reason why the code you've shown isn't working. Check the console for errors, or setup a working example of the issue in http://jsfiddle.net so we can see exactly how the HTML is setup and what the logic flow is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but we're working with a private framework so I cant really show you a jsfiddle cus we got form2tables and such. I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: That would indicate that the error is not in the block of code you've shown. The error should give you a file reference and line number from where it was thrown - check the code at that location.

Comment: The code is correct! Thanks. I doesnt upload the UI layer. we have 2 layers the HTML layer and the UI layer. But for some reasons it doesnt detect when it changes. Is there any kind of repaint options?

Comment: Fixed it via this way :
`$('.editor').val();
 $('.commentChoice').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
     $('.editor').val("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");
     $('.redactor_editor').html("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");`